# How to avoid blink of View when using animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I use translate and rotate animations to position `View` inside `FrameLayout` in `onCreate` event. I want animations to perform instantly so I set duration for both of them to 0. But when application starts there is a short blink of my `View` in top left corner of screen and then it becomes positioned according to animation parameters. How can I avoid this blink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spent whole day with that problem. fillAfter and fillBefore has nothing to do with that. Try this before animation start:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE); // view is our View we trying to animate
```

Then set animation listener for your animation:

```
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Is v and view the same?

Answer (score 4):

use `animation.setFillAfter(true)` or `animation.setFillBefore(true)`, depending on your needs. This should resolve the blink

Comment: Thanks, it is already set to true, but this does not solve my problem. I want animation to be instant, so user would see only end position of `View` without seeing its start position.

Comment: so why do you need an animation anyway? why don't you show your view to that position?

Comment: I need to rotate a View. Don't know how to do this without using animation.

Comment: create a custom view and in onDraw() method rotate your canvas

Answer (score 2):

Having a  tag inside the parent  tag of your animation file will cause this, try it with only one  tag and you will see the difference. I am working with this right now

Answer (score 0):

Odaym's answer is the solution for the issue actually. If you have something like that:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <set
        android:duration="1000">
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="100%"
            android:toXDelta="0"
            />
    </set>
</set>
```

Change it into this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="true" android:duration="1000">
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="100%"
            android:toXDelta="0"
            />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility after the animation execution code but not in "onAnimationEnd", also try to set the duration

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // view is our View we trying to animate
```